# modify the android.R.id.text1

Tags: android, textview

this is my MainActivity code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    pillAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,android.R.id.text1,list);
    getListView().setFooterDividersEnabled(true);

    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this);
    ImageButton footerView = (ImageButton)inflater.inflate(R.layout.footer_view,null);

    getListView().addFooterView(footerView);

   footerView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           Log.i(TAG,"Entered footerView.View.onClickListener");

           Intent pillIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),AddPill.class);
           startActivityForResult(pillIntent,ADD_PILL_ITEM_REQUEST);

       }
   });

    setListAdapter(pillAdapter);

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Log.i(TAG,"Entered onActivityResult");
    if(requestCode==ADD_PILL_ITEM_REQUEST){
        if(resultCode==RESULT_OK){
            pillStringName = data.getStringExtra("pillName");
            repeatedTimesStringName = data.getStringExtra("repeatedTimes");

            list.add(pillStringName);
            pillAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    }
}
```

my question is how I could modify the android.R.id.text1

I mean by that how I could edit the text view in lists to be for example: (center,text size...etc)

**Edit :**

I define my own custoem view like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/customTextView"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center"
android:textSize="40dp" >
</TextView>
```

after that I edit my code like this :

```
pillAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,R.id.customTextView,list);
```

this error appears to me in the LogCat :

[image]

correct answer :

after define your custom view you have replace the array adapter with you layout and your view name

in my case like this :

```
pillAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.pill_view,R.id.customTextView,list);
```

thanks for every one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a myview.xml for the simple custom textview:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/customTextView" 
 android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:padding="xxdp"
 android:textSize="xxsp" >
</TextView>
```

And use it in place of:

```
   android.R.id.text1
```

Comment: this error appear to me ( 3404-3404/com.example.kimo.pillreminder E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.kimo.pillreminder, PID: 3404
    android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f090047 type #0x12 is not valid)

Comment: and there is no error reference in LogCat to my code

Answer (score 0):

You need to create your own layout with TextView with parameters you'd like to have and use it instead of android.R.id.text1 (instead of this you will have your TextView id).